# SSRS - Multiple Tablix Filters Based on Mutiple Parameter Values

Tags: reporting-services, filter, parameters

I have an SSRS Report parameter set up with 3 different values ("Paid", "Denied" and "Open"). I want to set a tablix filter up so when the user selects one of the parameters, and a condition in the data is met, that row is returned. I want to give the user the option to select all there parameter values. 
When I use the following Expression into the Tablix filter(Paid), it works correctly:

```
=IIf(Parameters!ClaimStatus.Value(0) = "Paid"
    and Fields!TotalPaid.Value > "0"
, "Include"
, "Exclude")
```

If I try adding an additional filter(Denied) with the following Expression, neither filters work:

```
=IIf(Parameters!ClaimStatus.Value(0) = "Denied"
    and Fields!Denied.Value > "0"
, "Include"
, "Exclude")
```

Is it possible to pass multiple parameters into a Tablix Filter? I've searched all day with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it, do you have one or three multi valued parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up the filter to check the values in teh DataSet are 'IN' the multi-select parameter

In this example my DataSet has a field called `Status` which could be Open, Paid or Denied.

I also have a multi-select parameter as you describe above called `ClaimStatus`.

Using the `IN` operator makes the filter look for instances where Status is in the list of ClaimStatuses selected.  *Note the default when you add the ClaimStatus parmater as an expression is to add a `(0)` on the end.  **Remove this***

[image]

When this runs and I select Paid and Open, only the Paid an open records are returned in the table that has the results filtered.

[image]

Hopefully this will work for you.  Let me know if I can assist further.

Comment: That worked out for me. Thank you very much for your guidance.